# CodeIgniter : image upload on article

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

I'm building a website with MongoDB and Codeigniter where users can create articles (title + text) and after it (but before to submit), upload some pictures (images are not in the text).

I think i will use jquery.upload for it. But my question is how to do link between pictures and article (because img will be uploaded first), how to rename them ?, is there any good way to do this ?

Comment: r u trying to add 'an image field'? If so, I have codes for that.

Comment: Maybe, depends of what you have... Can I see your code?

Answer (score 0):

jquery upload would work. and check if it is success then create new hidden input into the form and set its value as you wish to use.

Comment: yes but what is user close his browser after uploaded image ? How to deal with that ?

Comment: use jquery and bind close window without submit, if yes then delete uploaded images that you wrote already in your hidden text.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never attempted this feature, this is a hypothetical solution that popped in my head:

Create a unique string on your Create Article page, and insert it into your document as a hidden field. A random string of 6 characters or something would probably be sufficient.

When uploading the images, use that string as an identifier for what future post the images belong to. Use the string in the file name, path, DB entry, or whatever's useful for your scenario.

When the article itself is submitted, the unique string will allow it to be identified with the images, and you can work whatever magic you need to at that stage to fully commit everything together.

Keep in mind that you should have some sort of statistics and/or garbage collection regarding any images that are uploaded and then the related article is abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'thumbnail' field in your table 'articles_table' . I removed the unnessary parts for simpler need.We will only use 'title' and 'thumbnail' as field.

View | create.php

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('articles/insert'); ?>       
  Title <br>
  <?php echo form_input('title','','id="title_input"'); ?><br>
   Thumbnail<br>  
   <input type="file" name="file" size="20" />
   <?php echo form_submit('Submit',"Submit"); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Controller | articles.php

```
function insert()
{
    //$this->articles_model->insert();
    $this->articles_model->save();
    redirect('articles/index');
}
```

Model | articles_model.php

```
    function save($id=0)
    {
        $title=$this->input->post('title');

                //Set the config
            $config['upload_path'] = './files/'; 
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|PNG'; 
            $config['max_size'] = '1100';
            $config['max_width'] = '11024';
            $config['max_height'] = '1768';
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE; 

            //Initialize
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            //Upload file
            if( ! $this->upload->do_upload("file"))
            {
               //echo the errors
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();
            }
            //If the upload success
            $thumbnail = $this->upload->file_name;

        if($id<1)
        {
            $data=array(
                'title'=>$title,
                'thumbnail'=>$thumbnail
            );
            $this->db->insert('articles_table',$data);
        }
      }
```